# Call mocked function from another function in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing a React App and I want to test whether my component correctly fetches the data; using Jest and Enzyme. I want to call a mocked function from another function I am mocking in my jest test:

```
const axios = jest.mock('axios', () => {
  const mockData = {
    schools: [
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'ABC',
        company: {
          id: 41,
          distance: '0.6 KM AWAY',
          logo: 'https://abc.xyz.jpg',
        },
        fee: 'NA',
        type: 'public',
        gender: 'Mixed',
      },
    ],
  };

  return {
    get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(mockData)),
  };
});

jest.fn('getData', () => {
  axios.get();
});

const props = {
  searchResult: {
    payload: [],
    isLoading: false,
    error: {},
    searchString: '',
  },
  getData: jest.fn(axios.get()),
};

it('fetch search data on click', () => {
  const search = shallow(<SearchComponent {...props} />);
  search
    .props()
    .getData()
    .then(() => {
      expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('data.json');
      expect(search.exists('search-result-card')).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Component code (just the important parts, can't paste the entire code as it's too big):

```
export class SearchResultComponent extends React.PureComponent {
render() {
       const { searchResult, getData } = this.props;
       <SearchInput
         placeholder="Enter keyword..."
         onClick={searchString => getData(searchString)}
       />
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I get this error:

```
TypeError: axios.get is not a function
```

What is wrong here, and how can I fix this?

Comment: why are you doing jest.fn('getData', () => {
  axios.get();
}); ? Isn't axios.get getting called from you component?

Comment: can you post your component code as well?

Comment: @eramit2010: The component has a child component which calls `getData`, which then calls the method doing fetch through `axios`.

Comment: @eramit2010: Added component code

Comment: you don't need to mock axios and everything to write unit test for this component. you might need to do that for testing parent component where getData is defined. For this component you can simply pass any mock function as getData and it should be called onClick of SearchInput.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://www.leighhalliday.com/mocking-axios-in-jest-testing-async-functions

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other issues as well, but I'll focus on answering the question asked which is why the following error occurs and how to fix it:

`TypeError: axios.get is not a function`

---

### Issue

`axios.get` is not a function so calling it when creating the implementation for the mock function for `props.getData` throws a `TypeError`.

---

### Details

`jest.mock` ["returns the `jest` object for chaining"](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options).

`const axios = jest.mock('axios', () => ...);` assigns `axios` to the `jest` object.

`axios.get()` runs to get the implementation of the mock function for the `getData` property of `props` (guessing `axios.get` should have been passed instead of `axios.get()`).

The `jest` object does not contain a definition for `get` so running `axios.get()` causes a `TypeError` indicating that `axios.get is not a function`.

---

### Solution

Import `axios` like normal at the top of your test file:

`import axios from 'axios';`

The [`jest.mock` call gets hoisted](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports) and runs first so importing `axios` like normal will import the mock.

`axios.get` will then refer to your mocked `get` function as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It gives more clarity on jest. However, I am still not able to successfully test my component. Can you point out the other issues you find in my solution? Also, I am not sure what all to test in this case? Should I just check the fetched data or should I also check if that fetched data is rendered correctly (which will happen on re-rendering when redux store gets updated with new data)? Latter case requires mounting the parent component which increases the complexity as I get other errors down the component hierarchy.